# ZoomIn or ZoomOut on click

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-2, zoom, events

I have this map with two controls

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Simple Map</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://openlayers.org/en/v3.17.1/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
    <script src="http://openlayers.org/en/v3.17.1/build/ol.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map" class="map"></div>
    <script>
      var map = new ol.Map({
        layers: [
          new ol.layer.Tile({
            source: new ol.source.OSM()
          })
        ],
        target: 'map',
        view: new ol.View({
          center: [0, 0],
          zoom: 2
        })
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I want to select `+` or `-`, and when it is selected, I want to zoom in or zoom out when I click on my map.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

first you'll have to create your html elements ( buttons, radio, ... ) where you want to put + and -, here is an example using buttons :

```
<button id="zoom-out">-</button>
<button id="zoom-in">+</button>
```

then you add a control on each one:

```
var zoomType;
document.getElementById('zoom-out').onclick = function() {
    zoomType="zoom-out";
};
document.getElementById('zoom-in').onclick = function() {
    zoomType="zoom-in";
};
```

Now you'll have to listen to the click event on the map :

```
map.on('click', function(evt) {
    if(zoomType=="zoom-in"){
         var view = map.getView();
         var zoom = view.getZoom();
         view.setZoom(zoom - 1);
    }
    if(zoomType=="zoom-out"){
         var view = map.getView();
         var zoom = view.getZoom();
         view.setZoom(zoom + 1);
    }
});
```